# Arithmetic Operator as enum?

Tags: java, enums, operators

My program prompts a user to select one of the arithmetic operators (+, -, *, /) and stores their response in the variable `inOperator`. In the following case statement (located in main method), I'd like to correspondingly set a `positiveOperaton` and `negativeOperation`.

```
switch (inOperator){
        case 1: operator = '+';
            //positiveOperation = plus
            //negativeOperation = minus
        break;

        case 2: operator = '-';
            //positiveOperation = minus
            //negativeOperation = plus
        break;

       ...
    }
```

I've already created an enum that *initializes* the arithmetic operations:

```
public enum Operator
{        
    plus("+") {
        @Override public double apply(double v1, double v2) {
        return v1 + v2;
        }
    },
    minus("-") {
        @Override public double apply(double v1, double v2) {
            return v1 - v2;
        }
    },

    ...

    private final String text;
    private Operator(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public abstract double apply(double x1, double x2);
    @Override public String toString() {
        return text;  
    }
}
```

So going back to the case statement, how can I set a `positiveOperation` and `negativeOperation`? Could I create another enum that *initializes* the two?

Comment: Why do you want both a `positiveOperation` and `negativeOperation`? Why not just have one `operation`?

Comment: What is the problem with `Operator.plus.apply(1.0, Operator.minus.apply(2.0, 3.0));` ?

Comment: **Where** is the `switch` statement you mention intended to be used? I thought I understood you, but now I'm uncertain.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The switch statement is in my main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
public enum Operator implements BinaryOperator<Double> {
    plus("+") {
        public Double apply(Double v1, Double v2) {
            return v1 + v2;
        }
    },
    minus("-") {
        public Double apply(Double v1, Double v2) {
            return v1 - v2;
        }
    };

    private final String text;

    Operator(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public static Operator from(String str) {
        return Arrays.stream(values()).filter(o -> o.text.equals(str)).findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure I understand the question, nor why you want to do this. Is the following what you mean?

```
switch (inOperator) {
case 1:
    operator = '+';
    positiveOperation = Operator.plus;
    negativeOperation = Operator.minus;
    break;

case 2:
    operator = '-';
    positiveOperation = Operator.minus;
    negativeOperation = Operator.plus;
    break;

// ...

}
```

Comment: That's what I want to implement, but I don't know how to  initialize positiveOperation and negativeOperation.

Comment: What do you mean by “initialize”? When in my code I write `positiveOperation = Operator.plus;`, I would call that initialization. I would love to help if understood what you’re asking for. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I phrased it pretty badly. I mean I don't know what sort of data type positiveOperation should be. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I thought that that was what your enum was for. For my code to compile I declared 
`int inOperator;` 
`char operator;` and 
`Operator positiveOperator;` (same for negative). I did ask myself whether you need this many types, though.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the user input to one of your operators, you can write a function like this:

```
public Operator operatorFromInput(char input) {
    switch (input) {
    case '+':
        return Operator.plus;
    case '-':
        return Operator.minus;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your enum:

```
public static Operator fromChar(String operator) {
    for (Operator op : Operator.values()) {
        if (op.text.equals(operator)) return op;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Received a fishy operator: " + operator);
}
```

Then once you read into inOperator you can do:

```
Operator operator = Operator.fromChar(inOperator);
int y = operator.apply(x1, x2);
```